# CheckedOutFiles return zero files but there are some files checked out

Tags: 2010, list, document-library, check-out

I've defined a Document Library named "Sales" on Sharepoint 2010. And I use the following code fragment to add all names who have checked out a file to a listbox:

```
lstCheckedOut.Items.Clear();

var docLib = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Sales"] as SPDocumentLibrary;

// Code fragment 1    
foreach (var doc in docLib.CheckedOutFiles) // No files are checked out ?
{
    lstCheckedOut.Items.Add(doc.CheckedOutBy.ToString());
}

// Code fragment 2
foreach (SPItem doc in docLib.Items)
{
    string name = doc["Checked Out To"] as string; // Just working fine ?

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        lstCheckedOut.Items.Add(name); 
    }
}
```

Why are no files present in the 'CheckedOutFiles' property ?

Comment: The user executing the code doesn't have the ability to see checked out files possibly?

Comment: But why does code fragment 2 work correctly, and code fragment 1  does not work ? It does not look permission related ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all values of the file this way:

```
        lstCheckedOut.Items.Clear();

        var docLib = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Sales"] as SPDocumentLibrary;

        // Code fragment 1    
        foreach (SPListItem doc in docLib.Items)
        {
            if (doc.File.CheckedOutByUser!=null)
            {
                lstCheckedOut.Items.Add(doc.File.CheckedOutByUser.ToString() + " checked out " + doc.File.Name.ToString());    
            }

        }
```